# Make a custom lastIndexOf method

Tags: java

```
int found = 0;
int index = 0;
while (index < list.size()) {
    if(list.get(index) == z) {
        found = index;
    }
    index++;
}
return found;
```

z is just the name of the object
I am trying to figure out why this is wrong for finding the lastIndexOf in an arraylist without using the lastIndexOf method that's already build into java.

could someone point my in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if the item have not been found, `found` will be equal to 0 which is a valid index and thus an invalid result. The expected value for when nothing have been found is -1

Comment: Just check the API for return values and maybe the simplest implementation in `ArrayList`'s own source.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.lastIndexOf%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to use `equals` and not compare references with `==`.

Second of all, you want the initial value of `found` to be `-1`, in case you don't find the element in the list (since otherwise you'll return `0`, which is a valid index, when the element is not found).

```
int found=-1;
int index=0;
while (index<list.size()){
    if(list.get(index).equals(z)){
        found=index;
    }
    index++;
}
return found;
```

Of course it would be more efficient to iterate from the end of the list backwards.

```
int index=list.size() - 1;
while (index >= 0){
    if(list.get(index).equals(z)){
        return index;
    }
    index--;
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Also why not start at the end of the array, and stop looking on first equal value found?

Comment: @lostbard Yep, I just added that.

Comment: this works great. seems like it was working if I used .equals but this iteration is much better and makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

1) You ought to return an index that is not a valid index of the container if an element is not found. Let's use -1, although the Java bods might do a better job than this such as returning a negative value related to where an element *would be* if it were in the container.

2) You need to start from the end of the list and work backwards. Else you will not necessarily find the last one.

3) Don't use `==` to compare values. Use `equals` instead.

Putting this together, having removed a redundant variable, gives you

```
int index;
for (index = list == null ? -1 : list.size() - 1; index >= 0; --index){
    if (list.get(index).equals(z)){
        break;
    }
}
return index;
```

There are probably better ways of traversing the container: I've unwittingly built an O(N * N) algorithm for containers where random lookup is O(N), but this ought to get you started.

Comment: Well at this point you might as well add the null handling otherwise it will throw a npe.

Comment: @MuratK.: Dunnit.

Comment: I see, but it should not be always -1 since you actually might want to find the index of the null object in the list. I am actually repeating what the open jdk body looks like :D This answer is fine as it is +1